# Activity 1 starts Activity 2 / Closing Activity 2 from Activity 1's callback

Tags: android

Here is some details to go with the title

*Step 1*: User is on **activity 1**, a post request is started

*Step 2*: While post request is happening an other activity starts, a webviewActivity. with a code like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(act, WrapperWebViewActivity.class);
        act.startActivity(intent);
```

with act beeing the **activity 1**

*Step 3*: **activity 1** get the callback from the post request, and now I want to finish my freshly started **activity 2**.

I've been seeing some topics here, but everytime they need to finish the **activity 1** from the **activity 2** when I want to finish **activity 2** from **activity 1**'s callback having **activity 2** in front

Comment: Have you used `startActivityForResult`?

Comment: Yes, but startActivityForResult would force me to set up the result in the **Activity 2** so basically it's the same problem to reach **activity 2** from **activity 1** callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the support. The solution was pretty simple

Inside `Activity 1` I set a variable like `isMyRequestComplete`

Inside `Activity 2` when I generate my webview i do something like `act1.getInstance().isMyRequestComplete()`

If yes, I do what I need to do (Close the webview/ load specific url or whatever)

If not, I'm looping for `100ms`.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think your concept is a bit risky..I'll explain why...

If you start A1 and then A2, and wait in A1 for the callback to close A2 one possible solution is that A1 is killed by system before post response comes (since you don't have control over activity life-cycle in general).

So, my suggestion would be:

- start request from A1 using intent service for server communication (requests).
- when you receive response fire some broadcast event
- in your A2 activity write some broadcast listener that listens for that broadcast event - and there finish the A2 (self)

IMHO, it's much safer approach.

Comment: Thanks for the sharing, 

I found an easy solution that will not scramble my architecture so I think I will go with that. Plus I don't understand how it's risky! A1 gets started, launches a webview in which I have the control (backpressed/pause/resume...). If the app is killed for any reason, the webview will showup again on the next launch!

Comment: I'm glad you found your solution...

It's risky if you want to accomplish scenario in 100% cases: when you get response from server -> close A2.
It could happen that your A2 activity keeps running even after you got post response  (this will happen in the case that A1 is killed by system in the meantime). 
If this is acceptable to you (that A2 keeps running after post response) then it's not risky, and your architecture works.

Comment: Just to add to clarify, once the activity goes in background, we don't have control in which moment android OS will kill it to free the resources, i.e. you don't know how much will your A1 instance be available, once you got A2 running.